# Why is the cache size identification register on ARM CPUs accessible from privileged modes only?

Tags: arm, computer-architecture

Is there any logical decision making behind this, to my understanding it exposes only the same information as CPUID instruction from x86 so why is it only made accessible to EL1? Is this in some way more secure, or perhaps it is just "over security"?

Comment: From a quick skim, most of the related registers including the equivalent of CPUID are also "privileged mode only". I suspect this is to avoid having to think about whether they might enable an exploit e.g. cache eviction timing attacks on processes by other users.

Comment: @pjc50 This was my first thought, but it seems to me a little lazy and I wonder if a sufficiently determined attacker could still perform cache timing attacks after some latency analysis. And it seems this is the case anyway: https://www.blackhat.com/docs/eu-16/materials/eu-16-Lipp-ARMageddon-How-Your-Smartphone-CPU-Breaks-Software-Level-Security-And-Privacy-wp.pdf

Comment: Maybe it's related to TrustZone. I note from http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7546496/ that cache lines can be flagged as "secure world only", and cache lines can be locked, so simply looking up the cache size doesn't guarantee that N lines are really available to user programs.

Answer (score 2):

It is to support the abstraction of user privilege level tasks from the hardware they are running on.

An Operating System can run at a higher privilege level and access the cache size data along with other data about the hardware it is running on. It is the responsibility of such an OS to deal with the hardware and abstract it from the user-level programs.

As far as possible, User-level tasks/processes should not be aware of the CPU they are running on. This prevents the writing of user-mode software that is 'tuned' to the particular hardware it is on. Such software may then not run correctly on a different CPU, reducing re-use and portability. Details such as the cache size are below the interest level of many programs.

The OS usually allows user task/processes to obtain hardware data that the OS/system designers think relevant or useful through the API (function calls to the OS).

Comment: Which in turn lets the user program access it and tune to its value. Also since many ARM systems run user code directly thats merely a nuisance. Discouraging a certain style to write application code on that level is hardly a good reason to hide information.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, which means the OS can choose to make that data available if the OS designers think it suitable. Or not. Why the downvote? These are standard design principles for a protected OS, the PC you're typing on employs these principles. It sounds like you're explaining your preference for CPU/OS design, not what's out there.

Comment: Downvote for explaining the presumed rationale of the architect?

Comment: @TonyM I'm sorry I don't see it, do you have any source to back up this being the driving factor behind the choice? The decision of whether a user can tune to the current processor is not down to the CPU designer, this should definitely be delegated to user.

Comment: It's not just the OS, there is a hypervisor to consider too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of speculation, but: ARM archtiectures have always been designed with multiprocessing in mind; even the most lowly Cortex-M0 has a lot of hardware automation when it comes to context switching, for example. Now, Cortex-M0 typically comes without a cache.

It's thoroughly thinkable that when they put in caches, the designers already thought of the possibility that an implementation by a silicon manufacturer would want to hide parts of the cache to user-run software, so that there's a logical problem with telling the userland software how large the cache is, because that size might not apply to them. Especially on Cortex-R, that would make a lot of sense – you might want to keep part of the "OS-level" data in a deterministic-latency cache, so you hide that cache from the other context. (Note that this is particularly easy on ARM – there's different stack modes that are controlled by a single register bit, and your cache controller could simply hinge onto that to decide whether it's OK to thrash a piece of cache or not.)